# ggplot: How to make the x/time-axis of a time-series plot only the time-component, not the date?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, lubridate

Consider the following example

```
library(lubridate)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
library(ggplot2)

dataframe <- data_frame(time = c(ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:00:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:01:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:02:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-04 00:03:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-05 00:00:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-06 00:01:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-07 00:02:00'),
                                 ymd_hms('2008-01-08 00:03:00')),
                        value = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8))

# A tibble: 8 × 2
                 time value
               <dttm> <dbl>
1 2008-01-03 19:00:00     1
2 2008-01-03 19:01:00     2
3 2008-01-03 19:02:00     3
4 2008-01-03 19:03:00     4
5 2008-01-04 19:00:00     5
6 2008-01-05 19:01:00     6
7 2008-01-06 19:02:00     7
8 2008-01-07 19:03:00     8
```

What I need to do is simple: I need to compute the average of `value` **at the same hour-minute-second** over all days in my sample, and plot it.

I have done the following:

```
dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
  mutate(hour = strftime(time, format="%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
  ungroup()

> dataframe
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      hour  mean
     <chr> <dbl>
1 19:00:00     3
2 19:01:00     4
3 19:02:00     5
4 19:03:00     6

ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = hour, y = mean, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2)
```

I have two problems with this approach

1. Obviously, R does not understand that the x-axis has a time meaning. This is just a character vector.
2. Therefore, I cannot control efficiently the x-axis using `scale_x_discrete(breaks= scales::pretty_breaks(n = 10)`. This is a big problem because my data is at the minutely frequency over a full day. Way too many labels on the x axis.

Can someone do better here? Is it possible to keep some sort of time variable on x-axis, even though there is no specific date associated with these hours?

Thanks!

Comment: just updated the libraries right now. Thanks @AlexeyFerapontov

Comment: what about scale_x_date?

Comment: @Haboryme `Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only`

Comment: "*Obviously, R does not understand that the x-axis has a time meaning*" If you keep it in a POSIX class and use `scale_x_datetime` ggplot2 will understand the time meaning very well. The problem is created when you extract only the hour with `strftime`.

Comment: thanks @Gregor this is what I am trying to do. How can I keep the posix class while still aggregating at the hour level (and then losing the day information)?

Comment: Spoof it. Add the date information back in, and make it all the same day.

Comment: could you please write down this as an answer? not sure how to add back a fake date.

Comment: @Gregor I think the challenge is to have a plot where the x-axis only shows the hours of the day (and not the fake date).

Comment: The documentation is very helpful for that challenge. See especially the Examples at the bottom of `?scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: The title was not good. *"How to label the x-axis of a time series plot when the x-variable is a character?*" is an XY question. The real underlying question was *"How to make the x/time-axis of a TS plot only the time-component, not the date"*. (*"Should I extract time as character...?"* would go in the details)

Comment: @smci I see your point but the problem starts with a character that gets converted to a date afterwards. so i does not make entirely sense to mention the time component of it in the title already. maybe we can mix our titles 

Comment: Ok, sure. Main thing is we isolated the bad assumption causing the grief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We just need a POSIX datetime with all the hours having the same date. The date doesn't matter, pick any you like:

```
dataframe <- dataframe %>% 
  mutate(hour = strftime(time, format="%H:%M:%S")) %>% 
  group_by(hour) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(value)) %>% 
      # add the date back in
  mutate(x_date = ymd_hms(paste("2008-01-01", hour))) %>%
  ungroup()

ggplot(dataframe, aes(x = x_date, y = mean, group = 1)) + 
  geom_line(size = 2)
```

[image]

Just like numbers between 1 and 10 aren't labeled by default as 001, 002, 003, etc., datetimes on the same day won't be labeled with the date and the time by default. The defaults can be modified in `scale_x_datetime`.

Comment: thanks, but actually given that my times span from `00:00` in the morning to `23:59` at the very end of the day, I do see my fake date showing up on my x-axis. Any ideas how to get rid of it?

Comment: Follow the examples at the bottom of `?scale_x_datetime`. The documentation is actually quite good.

Comment: `labels = date_format("%H:%M")` of course!! thanks @Gregor for the idea.